# Allow a User Group to access plugin pages (without hasCpSection)

Tags: plugin-development, users, control-panel, permissions

I'm facing a problem which, on the surface, seems similar to [this thread...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11170/cannot-grant-user-group-plugin-permission-without-hascpsection)

Like that other thread, I've found that a specific user group is unable to access my plugin's pages because the plugin is lacking a [`hasCpSection`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/templates#giving-your-plugin-its-own-cp-section) method. My plugin doesn't *need* a `hasCpSection` method, because there really isn't a "section" for people to access. Specifically, **I don't need a link in the side nav, because my plugin doesn't have a main index page.**

However, my plugin *does* have other pages. These other pages are only accessible via special links. Those special links appear on Entry edit pages, as a custom Fieldtype. **These random pages are what I want my client to have access to.**

[image: "Unauthorized" message]

And that's where I'm unable to use the solution provided in the related thread. Because when I link directly to a template, **those pages are restricted by default.** There's no way for me to "allow anonymous". I would have to give the user group full admin access (which is crazy), and *then* circle back and restrict permissions on the page.

Any suggestions? This kinda feels like a bug to me, or perhaps a feature request.

Comment: Did the solution to this question solve your problem? I'm running into exactly the same issue. I was already using a Controller and I still get the Unauthorized message if I use the "login as" option on a non-admin user.

Answer (score 2):

Register new user permissions to restrict access to those pages using the [`registerUserPermissions`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerUserPermissions) hook.
Then use [`registerCpRoutes`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerCpRoutes) to setup routes to a controller action which checks for required user permissions before rendering the templates.

Sorry if I’m missing something, but I don’t see how this has anything to do with the `hasCpSection` function.

Comment: Interesting... You're suggesting a route which points to a **controller action**. Currently, my route points **directly at the template**. Which is where `hasCpSection` comes in... direct access to the template is unavailable unless I have a `hasCpSection` method.

Comment: Interesting indeed. It would be nice if the `registerCpRoutes` hook was documented a bit better, this is not the first time it surprises me with unexpected behavior (`hasCpSection` effecting routes to templates but not to custom controller actions).